# SonarQube Category Explanations

Tags: sonarqube

Can anybody suggest a one/two line explanation of the "five" SonarQube categories, in such a way that a non-developer can understand what the percentage figure means?

- Efficiency
- Maintainability
- Portability
- Reliability
- Usability

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One word "synonym" for non-developers (not exact synonym though, but enough to give a quick idea):

- Efficiency : performance
- Maintainability : evolution
- Portability : reuse
- Reliability : resilience
- Usability : design

---

Most of those metrics are presented in this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality)

- Efficiency:

> Efficiency IT metrics **measure the performance of an IT system**.
>   An effective IT metrics program should measure many aspects of performance including throughput, speed, and availability of the system.

- Maintainability
  .
  is the ease with which a product can be maintained in order to:

  - correct defects
  - meet new requirements
  - make future maintenance easier, or
  - cope with a changed environment

.

- Portability:

the software  codebase feature to **be able to reuse the existing code instead of creating new code when moving software from an environment to another**.

- Reliability:

The IEEE defines reliability as "**The ability of a system or component to perform its required functions under stated conditions for a specified period of time**."

Note from this paper:

> To most project and software development managers, *reliability is equated to correctness*, that is, they look to testing and the number of "bugs" found and fixed.
>   While finding and fixing bugs discovered in testing is necessary to assure reliability, a better way is to develop a robust, high quality product through all of the stages of the software lifecycle.
>   That is, **the reliability of the delivered code is related to the quality of all of the processes and products of software development; the requirements documentation, the code, test plans, and testing**.

- Usability

studies the **elegance and clarity with which the interaction with a computer program or a web site (web usability) is designed**.

Usability differs from user satisfaction insofar as the former also embraces usefulness (see [Computer user satisfaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_user_satisfaction)).

See for instance [usabilitymetrics.com](http://www.usabilitymetrics.com/)

Answer (score -1):

This represents for each category the density of violations (non-respect) of rules in the source code.